# get data from server in the Angular JS application config

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I'm trying to use angular-translate to translate labels following user's language.
and I'm referring to this [exampe](http://plnkr.co/edit/KnrKTst5dWXvlZNeIy9c?p=preview)
However I need to get those details from database, so is there any way to get that done? I saw that there is some example using json files like this [one](http://embed.plnkr.co/h7qUlY/)
however how can we do that using `$http` or `$httpprovider` to get data from database?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to get the translations from database?

Comment: @Martin yes, that's it. I want to load translation from database and not from local files.

Comment: You should map your translations from the database to a json output, wich you load. On your server side you need to map the data to json.

Comment: @BoVandersteene you mean using json files like this [example](http://embed.plnkr.co/h7qUlY/)

Comment: @Med yes, you need to generate files lake that